# What are the scientific inspirations for Steins;Gate?

Tags: steins-gate

You know how they mention the LHC and about how it could create mini black holes and stuff like the world-line ideas

Also how the 36-bytes limit works for a D-mail and the theories behind the time-leap machine. Where do you think they got that from?

Comment: Ugh not at all.

Comment: Related on [physics.se] sister site: [Can black holes be created on a miniature scale?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22578/can-black-holes-be-created-on-a-miniature-scale), although you probably have to list more than "*and stuff*". Anyway, time-leap machine is still an impossible thing, so I don't know how it can be accurate. Otherwise, scientists can just do what this anime did, and earth will become a better place (or not).

Comment: It was  36 bytes, btw. Not like it matters though.

Comment: @AkiTanaka ehh I see what you mean by not being possible, though the theories may be based on real-life theories, as the "world line" thing is actually based on one of the multiverse theory.

Comment: Ah, okay, I see what you meant. You're asking whether the theories inside the anime (and/or VN) were based on existing theories from real-world, not self made-up... but not about it's truthiness. Am I correct in interpreting your question?

Comment: Yep thats what I mean :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about whether anime/manga are realistic are off-topic as per https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/668. Such questions require expertise about science/engineering which are outside the scope of this site, so we can't expect users here to accurately answer/vote on them. As per the answer there, changing the question to "What are the scientific inspirations for Steins;Gate?" would make it acceptable.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I just realized I got off topic there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most unrealistic part of the time-leap machine is that they had to decompress that 36-byte message and put it back to one's head. And they just used a cellphone for that.

---

Regarding to compressing a huge amount of data to a 36-byte (288-bit) message - yes, it's totally possible. However there should be a decompressor which would also use a huge amount of data.

Using a black hole for "compression"? It's a joke. Actual compression doesn't work like this. It's all about making tables or "dictionaries". Here's a simple algorithm which can compress any amount of data to a 1-byte message (sometimes it can not):

Compressor: replace "apple" with "1", "orange" with "2", anything else with "3:anything else".
Decompressor: replace "1" with "apple", "2" with "orange", message like "3:anything else" with anything else.

See? It can compress 5-byte and 6-byte messages to a 1-byte message!

Answer (score 0):

So the LHC creating mini-blackholes was a preliminary fear [held by non-researchers about CERN.](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2016/03/11/could-the-lhc-make-an-earth-killing-black-hole/#2c8eecbc2ed5)

The mini-blackholes themselves are NOT how time travel works, they aren't used for compression or decompression, the fact is the blackhole size or power or "something" determined the maximum amount of data that could go back in time. Actually it stated outright that the travel through the blackholes in Steins;gate is specifically a Kerr Black Hole. [more information is here.](http://www.strangerdimensions.com/2012/07/17/could-a-kerr-black-hole-be-used-to-travel-through-time/)